# vector space constructed through a torsion module

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain, $p \in R$ a prime element and $M$ a finitely generated $p$-torsion module of the form:
$$
M = R/(p^{e_1}) \oplus \dots \oplus R/(p^{e_t}).
$$

Let now be $_pM = \{m \in M \mid p m = 0\}$.

I now want to show that $_pM$ is a $R/(p)$-vector space of dimension $t$.

Thanks in advance. I'm not very used to these constructions.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you see that it is a module over $R/(p)$, which is a field?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Aw man! I was just about to write something extremely similar to this. Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${}_pM=\bigoplus_{i=1}^t(p^{e_i-1})/(p^{e_i})\simeq\bigoplus_{i=1}^tR/(p).$$

Indeed, if $\bar x=x+(p^{e_i})$ is an element of $R/(p^{e_i})$, we have:
$$p \bar x=\bar 0\iff px\in(p^{e_i})\iff x\in (p^{e_i-1})$$
since $p$ is a prime element.

Comment: Thanks, but could you maybe elaborate why $_pM$ has exactly the shape ${}_pM=\bigoplus_{i=1}^t(p^{e_i-1})/(p^{e_i})$?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: Okay yes, that makes it clearer, thanks.